# Dart classes for models from JSON (code generation)

Tags: dart, code-generation

I was looking at this thread: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/0pv-Uaq8FGI but still cannot find a solution for what I would like to have on the client side (possible on the server as well).

I imagine there should be a way to provide a standard format for data structure that is represented as JSON object in JS land (for example json schema or yaml or whatever) that could be used as input to generate Dart classes that contain the fromJSON constructor and toJSON method (possible some checks as well for the data ranges) that the developer can then extend if additional logic is needed over the data coming over the wire.

I do not want to use mirrors if possible, instead the classes should be statically generated (i.e. run a tool -> get the class(es) to match the latest schema/input).

Can you point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Optionally, I remember someone from Google mention that they use json serialization for protobuf as it works faster in the browser, maybe it is possible to use proto definition for messages but still transmit them as JSON (kind of like the messages in gmail?)

Comment: Do you want to create Dart objects from a JSON string that comes from the network, or from a Javascript object?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53270688

Answer (score 1):

There is a great package called `json_serializable` on [pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable) that creates serializers for your models via code generation.

You can customize the generated code via annotations or you can just modify the generated code by hand.