# How to generate Dart code from json structure

Tags: dart, flutter, code-generation

The `code_build` (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/code_builde) package provides a solution to generate classes and constructors, field and methods for that class.

My ultimate goal is to generate Flutter (https://flutter.io) Widgets based on the json structure given, but I don't know how to do this with the `code_build` or another package.

So help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

The general way to write something which outputs Dart code is to wrap up the functionality in a [`Builder`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/build/latest/build/Builder-class.html) and to perform the code generation with [`build_runner`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/build_runner)

At a high level you'd write a `Builder` that:

- Has `buildExtensions` of `{".json": [".dart"]}`.
- Reads in the `buildStep.inputId` asset and parses the json.
- Uses `code_builder` to build up a String and then write it to the output asset.

Then you'd [configure the builder in `build.yaml`](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/tree/master/build_config#defining-builders-to-apply-to-dependents-similar-to-transformers). And either apply it manually to your package, or if you'd like to publish it as a utility it can apply to dependencies.

Your package would have a `dev_dependency` on `build_runner` and then you can execute builds with `flutter packages run build_runner build`.

There are more docs at https://github.com/dart-lang/build/tree/master/docs

You can see an example of a package which does something similar - starts with yaml files and outputs Dart files using `code_builder` at https://github.com/natebosch/message_builder

Answer (score 0):

There is now an online tool which will generate the Dart classes from a JSON payload if you're only looking to structure your model classes. It won't do it dynamically at runtime, but it's super helpful when you're first building your program.

https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/